# Meaning of 'Expected a type"?

Tags: google-maps, flutter

After initiating 'flutter run', I got the following error:

error: expected a type
    - (void)setCameraTargetBounds:(GMSCoordinateBounds_Nullable*)bounds;

This is the line of code associated with the error:

- (void)setCameraTargetBounds:(GMSCoordinateBounds_Nullable*)bounds;

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Code snipper:

```html
// Defines map UI options writable from Flutter.
@protocol FLTGoogleMapOptionsSink
- (void)setCameraTargetBounds:(GMSCoordinateBounds*)bounds;
- (void)setCompassEnabled:(BOOL)enabled;
- (void)setMapType:(GMSMapViewType)type;
- (void)setMinZoom:(float)minZoom maxZoom:(float)maxZoom;
- (void)setRotateGesturesEnabled:(BOOL)enabled;
- (void)setScrollGesturesEnabled:(BOOL)enabled;
- (void)setTiltGesturesEnabled:(BOOL)enabled;
- (void)setTrackCameraPosition:(BOOL)enabled;
- (void)setZoomGesturesEnabled:(BOOL)enabled;
- (void)setMyLocationEnabled:(BOOL)enabled;
```

Comment: Could you post a code snippet where you got this error instead of just this one line?

Comment: @matkv code snippet added